# Load and show videos at the same speed as in native windows directory, C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making an WPF application, where I want to show all videos contains in the current directory as same, as I would open folder in native windows os. It's okay, when I put only one media element and start the application - so it loads fast as it should be, but when I put there for example 100 media elements with random size and length, it loads so slow, and I have to wait for all content before it loads. So how do I make it load so faster? PS. It's okay, if there will not be mediaelement, but there should be picture of video from first frame (same as it is in native windows os).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    const string CONTENT_PATH = @"C:\Users\videos\";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        foreach (string filepath in Directory.GetFiles(CONTENT_PATH))
        {
            MediaContent.Children.Add(MainWindow.createVideoElement(filepath));
        }
    }

    public static MediaElement createVideoElement(string filepath)
    {
        MediaElement video = new MediaElement();
        video.Source = new Uri(filepath);
        video.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        video.ScrubbingEnabled = true;

        video.Width = 240;
        video.Height = 240;

        video.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); 
        video.Stop();

        return video;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a background task to load your video elements

Comment: Windows uses pre-computed thumbnail images stored in the thumbs.db file to make showing the image preview faster. You'll probably have to implement a similar thing or find out a way to use the thumbs.db yourself

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will look on it.

Comment: Hi @RodiaxLenon, I'm suffering from the same problem, I want to Load and show videos at the same speed. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or ideas. Thank